# Convexity, coercivity and countinuous of functional

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

We have $V=W_0^{1,2}(I)$. Consider minimization problem of functional $F:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where:

$F(x)=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{2}(x\prime)^2-\sin{(\frac{1}{2}\pi\sigma)x d\sigma}$

$x(-1)=x(1)=1$. Does the Gateaux differential exist? Does the Gateaux derivative exist? If they exist, find them out. Solve the second derivative of $F$ at the point $x$ in direction $h$ and $w$. Proof convexity, coercivity and if the functional is contiuous? Does it have minimum?

Comment: What's your thought on the problem so far? What have you tried?

Comment: As written, this comes across as a homework problem.  People will be much more receptive if you explain the question's context and, more importantly, what efforts you've already made to try to solve it.

Comment: I already have Gateuax derivative, second derivative too. But I dont know that properties, how proof them. Convexity:
$d^{2}F(x_{0};h,h)\geq 0$ 
$d^{2}F(x_{0};h,h)=\int_{-1}^{1}{{(h^\prime)}^2 d\sigma}\geq 0$

This should be right. But for continuous and coercivity, I should it proof with this type of eq. 
 
$F(x)= a(x,x)-L(x)$

I also should use Poincaré-Friedrich inequality. Thanks a lot

Comment: Usually, Lebesque dominated convergence theorem is very helpful in calculating Gateaux derivatives of such forms.